# tumblr user name from url

Tags: regex, url, tumblr

How can we extract 'tumblr' username from urls using regex?
urls could be

```
http://tname.tumblr.com/
http://www.tname.tumblr.com
tname.tumblr.com
http://www.tumblr.com/blog/tname
tname.tumblr.com/post/1234567
www.tname.tumblr.com.
```

I only want tname to be printed. I tried using Regex but can only do either string beginning with http or www.

Thanks
R

Comment: What regex/other methods have you already tried, and what language are you ultimately using this in?

Comment: I am trying to use sqlclr.

Comment: I am trying to use sqlclr. SELECT id,
          SUBSTRING(RegExReplace(url,'.tumblr.com[\W+]*','',1), 
                      len(RegExParse(url, '^(www.|http://)*', 1)) + 1,
                          len(RegExReplace(url,'.tumblr.com[\W+]*','',1))) from tumblr_tbl
WHERE  RegExIsMatch(url, '(.tumblr.com)', 1) = 1

Answer (score 2):

Your example is SQL, not SQLCRL, which is intended to allow the use of .NET languages in stored procedures/etc on SQL Server. I personally would recommend not injecting regex into your SQL query, and use one of the .NET languages in conjunction with SQL to pull this out.

I'm not familiar with using `RegExParse` or `RegExReplace` in your context, but the following regex should successfully match `tname` (or any other alphanumeric username) in all of your example lines, without the need for string manipulation or replacement:

```
[^"\/www\."](?<!w{3})[A-Za-z0-9]*(?=\.tumblr\.com)|(?<=\.tumblr\.com\/blog\/).*
```

That's a bit of a beast, but essentially it uses some [regex lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to pull out just the username.

Here's how the matching looks (using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy.html)):

[image: RegexBuddy matching]